# How can I iterate through lists and return the URL if a class inside the list contains a certain string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, each

I'm currently new to JQuery and I am fiddling around in JSFiddle in hopes of honing my skills to develop a web app I've had on my mind.

One requirement I am meant to fulfill, is to iterate through lists on the page, and if a certain class contains a string I'm looking for, return the URL of another class inside that list. Once that's done, it will iterate onto the next list item.

```js
$('.listItems li').each(function() {
if ('.spanClass' == 'True') {
    var hrefValue = $('.aClass').attr('href');
    alert (hrefValue);
}
})
```

```html
<li class="listItems">
  <a class="aClass" href="/home">
   <span class="spanClass">True</span>
 </a>
</li>
<li class="listItems">
 <a class="aClass" href="/town">
   <span class="spanClass">False</span>
 </a>
</li>
<li class="listItems">
  <a class="aClass" href="/home">
    <span class="spanClass">True</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

In theory, I am hoping my code will alert me of the URL if the span class spanClass contains 'True'.

How can I fix my code so I am able to fetch the URL if a class contains a specific string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var href = $('li.listItems .spanClass:contains(True)').map(function() {
  

  return $(this).parent('a').attr('href')
}).get();

console.log(href)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="listItems">
    <a class="aClass" href="/home">
      <span class="spanClass">True</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="listItems">
    <a class="aClass" href="/town">
      <span class="spanClass">False</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="listItems">
    <a class="aClass" href="/home">
      <span class="spanClass">True</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. Use `.map()` to get the href and put in an array

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. Thank you so much!

Comment: @juiceb0xk glad to help mate happy coding

Comment: How come I can execute this via CTRL+ENTER on JSFiddle, but when i input the code into Chrome's console, all that is displayed is a '[]'. When I execute the code in JSFiddle, the array is returned, but not in chrome?

Comment: this condition might be having the problem `:contains(True)` your span has `True` text?are you using same html mark up?

Comment: It's all the same, it's just that I am returned with undefined, whereas executing the code in JSFiddle returns the array with the values inside.

Comment: Hmm, it has decided to work now for some unknown reason. Any who, I'll go ahead and accept your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @juiceb0xk if you need help just comment i will help if i know how

Answer (score 0):

Hope it help :

```
//HTML
<ul class="listItems">
    <li>
      <a class="aClass" href="/home">
       <span class="spanClass">True</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="aClass" href="/town">
       <span class="spanClass">False</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="aClass" href="/home">
        <span class="spanClass">True</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    </ul>



//JS

    $('.listItems li').each(function(idx) {
    if($(this).find('.spanClass').html() == 'True')
    {
            var hrefValue = $('.aClass').attr('href');
        alert (hrefValue);
    }
    })
```